# Custom taxonomy archive page not routing?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

I have a plugin free custom post type and taxonomy setup - see below. From this I get an archive of the CPT at:

```
/archives/nomination-archive
```

If I use the_terms( $post->ID, 'nomination_type' ,  ' ' ) I get a nice link to my taxonomy term archives in each of my nomination posts i.e:

```
/archives/nomination-type/best-2013
```

Going to this url gives me an archive page with a title "Best 2013" as you would expect, but I can't for the life of me get it to show any posts..refreshed permalinks etc etc

Any help much appreciated...

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_nomination_post_type' );
function create_nomination_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'nomination',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Nominations' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Nomination' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Nomination' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 6,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'nomination-archive'),
        'supports' => array( 
          'title', 
          'editor',
          'author',
          'thumbnail',
          'page-attributes'
           ),
        )
    );
}

//
// Add nominatons type taxonomy
//
function add_nomination_type_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy('nomination_type', 'nomination', array(
        // Hierarchical taxonomy (like categories)
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x( 'Nomination Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Nomination Categories', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Nomination Categories' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Nomination Categories' ),
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Nomination Categories' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Nomination Category:' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Nomination Category' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Nomination Category' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Nomination Category' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Nomination Category Name' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Nomination Item Categories' )
        ),
         //Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'nomination-type' // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
          //    'with_front' => true, // Don't display the category base before "/genres/"
            //'hierarchical' => false // Allows good urls
        )
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_nomination_type_taxonomies', 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be an idiot - not sure. Probably indicates I am.

Setting 'exclude_from_search' to 'false' for the CPT clears up this problem.

Still not quite sure why the CPT archive works and the taxonomy ones do not when 'exclude_from_search' is 'true' but there you go.